# How to test if a method is const?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

How can I get a boolean value indicating if a known method has the const qualifier or not?

For example:

```
struct A {
    void method() const {}
};

struct B {
    void method() {}
};

bool testA = method_is_const<A::method>::value; // Should be true
bool testB = method_is_const<B::method>::value; // Should be false
```

In the `type_traits` header I found an `is_const` test I could use, but I need the method type, and I'm unsure how to obtain that.

I tried: `std::is_const<decltype(&A::method)>::value` but it doesn't work, and I can understand why (`void (*ptr)() const) != const void (*ptr)()`).

Comment: To address the last part there, that's because the first is a constant function pointer returning void, and the second is a function pointer returning const void.

Comment: Also, I am going to speculate that is_const is catching the return type and not the const qualifier on the function itself. However, I can't properly answer this as I'm not sure how to make it behave as you want it to.

Comment: @William Thanks for the help. Yeah, I don't know how to check that const qualifier =/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a lot simpler to check whether a member function can be called on a `const`-qualified lvalue.

```
template<class T>
using const_lvalue_callable_foo_t = decltype(std::declval<const T&>().foo());

template<class T>
using has_const_lvalue_callable_foo = std::experimental::is_detected<const_lvalue_callable_foo_t, T>;
```

Rinse and repeat, except with `std::declval<const T>()`, to check if said function can be called on a `const`-qualified rvalue. I can think of no good use cases for `const &&` member functions, so whether there's a point in detecting this case is questionable.

Consult the current [Library Fundamentals 2 TS working draft](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v2/fundamentals-ts.html#meta.detect) on how to implement `is_detected`.

---

It is a lot more convoluted to check whether a particular pointer-to-member-function type points to a function type with a particular *cv-qualifier-seq*. That requires 6 partial specializations per *cv-qualifier-seq* (`const`  and `const volatile` are different *cv-qualifier-seq*s), and still can't handle overloaded member functions or member function templates. Sketching the idea:

```
template<class T> 
struct is_pointer_to_const_member_function : std::false_type {};

template<class R, class T, class... Args> 
struct is_pointer_to_const_member_function<R (T::*)(Args...) const> : std::true_type {};

template<class R, class T, class... Args> 
struct is_pointer_to_const_member_function<R (T::*)(Args...) const &> : std::true_type {};

template<class R, class T, class... Args> 
struct is_pointer_to_const_member_function<R (T::*)(Args...) const &&> : std::true_type {};

template<class R, class T, class... Args> 
struct is_pointer_to_const_member_function<R (T::*)(Args..., ...) const> : std::true_type {};

template<class R, class T, class... Args> 
struct is_pointer_to_const_member_function<R (T::*)(Args..., ...) const &> : std::true_type {};

template<class R, class T, class... Args> 
struct is_pointer_to_const_member_function<R (T::*)(Args..., ...) const &&> : std::true_type {};
```

If you want `const volatile` to be `true` too, stamp out another 6 partial specializations along these lines.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is that link you referenced? Does it contain official extensions that are already available in a C++X standard, or is it a proposal for a future version?

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho It's a working draft for a proposed technical specification. Things in there are likely to go into the next version of the C++ standard. As to `is_detected`, it was voted in two weeks ago, so probably there's no implementation available yet, but the TS supplies a full implementation of it, so you can just take it and use it.

Comment: Your implementation ignores functions which can only be called on rvalues, doesn't it?

Comment: @Columbo Sure, but do you really care? I see no good use case for a `const &&`  member function.

Comment: @T.C. Plus `volatile`, no?

Comment: @Columbo well, we can use `const T` instead of `const T &`. The arguable benefit is that a `const &` function will still work, unless it's overloaded with a `const && = delete;`.

Comment: @T.C. It is entirely irrelevant whether good use-cases exist or not. It is relevant whether your implementation is accurate, which it is not. Fix it, or not, I just noted it so you could potentially adjust it or add a note.

Comment: @Barry First one or second? First, no, second, depends on whether you want `const volatile` to count as `const`.

Comment: @T.C. Or what about doing to tests, one for `T const&` and one for `T const`?

Comment: @T.C. The question asks "if a known method has the const qualifier or not", and `const volatile` methods do have that qualifier. It's possible that the OP meant to ask something else instead, but based on the question, I agree with Barry, you'd need an additional 6 partial specializations.

Comment: @Columbo Feel free to suggest better names.

Comment: A use for `const&&`: pseudo reference read op.  All methods `&&` to make naive storage break: read ops `const` (as they don't modify).  At best marginal reason, but is a reason.

Answer (score 8):

The reason `std::is_const<decltype(&A::method)>::value` doesn't work is that a const member function isn't a const (member function). It's not a top-level `const` in the way that it would be for `const int` vs `int`.

What we can do instead is a type trait using `void_t` that tests whether we can call `method` on a const `T`:

```
template <typename... >
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_const_callable_method : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct is_const_callable_method<T, void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<const T&>().method())
    > > : std::true_type { };
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b77899ca1f81272)

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, things get a lot easier because [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) have been standardized, which subsumes the detection idiom.

Now all we need to write is this constraint:

```
template<class T>
concept ConstCallableMethod = requires(const T& _instance) {
    { _instance.method() }
};
```

`ConstCallableMethod` tests that the expression `_instance.has_method()` is well formed given that `_instance` is a const-reference type.

Given your two classes:

```
struct A {
    void method() const { }
};

struct B {
    void method() { }
};
```

The constraint will be `true` for `A` (`ConstCallableMethod<A>`) and `false` for `B`.

---

If you wish to *also* test that the return type of the `method` function is void, you can add  `->void` to the constraint like so:

```
template<class T>
concept ConstCallableMethodReturnsVoid = requires(const T& _instance) {
    { _instance.method() } -> void
};
```

---

If you wish to be a little more generic, you can pass in a member function pointer to the concept and test if that function pointer can be called with a `const` instance (although this gets a little less useful when you have overloads):

```
template<class T, class MemberF>
concept ConstCallableMemberReturnsVoid = requires(const T& _instance, MemberF _member_function) {
    { (_instance.*_member_function)() } -> void
};
```

You'd call it like so:

```
ConstCallableMemberReturnsVoid<A, decltype(&A::method)>
```

This allows for some other theoretical class like `C`, that has a const method, but it's not named `method`:

```
struct C
{
    void foobar() const{}
};
```

And we can use the same concept to test:

```
ConstCallableMemberReturnsVoid<C, decltype(&C::foobar)>
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Vx75Dy7hHFfKHEfN)

Answer (score 2):

Create a type trait to determine the const-ness of a method:

```
template<typename method_t>
struct is_const_method;

template<typename CClass, typename ReturnType, typename ...ArgType>
struct is_const_method< ReturnType (CClass::*)(ArgType...)>{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename CClass, typename ReturnType, typename ...ArgType>
struct is_const_method< ReturnType (CClass::*)(ArgType) const>{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```